# TCP implementation

Tags: tcp, network

Can one speed up TCP transmission of packets if the no.of bits in sequence field and no. Of bits in acknowledgement field are reduced ? If yes , then how much time is saved? Mathematical equations for solution would help.

Comment: Why do you think this might be possible? Do you just ask out of the blue or do you have some specific idea on why this might work?

Comment: That question is really pure speculation about a protocol that does not exist. Changing that would make it something other than TCP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence/ack fields need to be considerably larger than any possible send window to avoid ambiguity. If you redesign TCP with those fields reduced you end up with a small send window, resulting in poor performance with high bandwidth & high latency connections (LFNs).

The send window needs to be able to get as large as the product of bandwidth and round-trip time, or you limit throughput to window size divided by RTT.